# Using Point as the geom type in pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting, point, linestring

in my table i have the field geom(POINT, srid) and its populated, this table also have the source an target field witch is blank(just like pgrouting guide).

I tried the function pgr_createTopology() and it returns ok, created the vertex_pgr table but it is empty.

Must the geom field be a geom(LINESTRING)?

My problem is: i have some points and need to trace routes between them.

Do i have to make line string between my points?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, you need a linestring network. Points won't work.

But if you can turn your points into lines, for example if your points are GPS traces with a timestamp, then you first need to use a PostGIS function like [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) and then you can "node" your network as described [here](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/node_network.html#pgr-node-network).